# Why do we need a whole field of operators in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-states

This is probably a very silly question, so I hope you'll excuse my ignorance of QFT.  As far as I can tell, there are really two mathematical objects in the Hamiltonian formulation:

1. The state vector, aka. wavefunction, which is a linear combination of basis Fock states.  This is the only physically measurable entity, as it gives the probability distribution of possible particle configurations/energies/momenta, according to which basis you're working in.
2. The field of operators, one for each point in spacetime.  Okay, there are two conjugate fields that obey the canonical commutation relations.

The dynamics is: you integrate the operator field in a certain way to obtain the Hamiltonian, and then use the Hamiltonian to evolve the state vector, and in principle that's all there is to it.  (I believe this is called the Schrodinger picture?)

But then, the only operator we ultimately need is the Hamiltonian.  So why bother defining a whole field worth of operators?

My guess is, it is about Lorentz invariance.  When you Lorentz-boost to a new reference frame, you change the 3D space you integrate over to get the Hamiltonian.  And the field of operators is somehow set up so that you get the right Hamiltonian in each frame, magically making the theory invariant.

Is that on the right track?  If so, what is the law governing the operator field itself, that gives it this magical property?  Is it just the commutation relations themselves?

Or, as is more likely, am I missing something much more fundamental here?

To illustrate, is it possible to describe the operator field corresponding to an actual physical experiment?  Or is that infeasible?

Comment: You're on the right track and hitting on a subtle point. Lorentz invariance is not *manifest*, or obvious, in the operator formalism. In addition, fields are useful because they guarantee *locality*. Interactions should happen at a single point. This is important for *causality*, because the time ordering of spacelike separated events is ambiguous in special relativity. However, to give a full explanation of all the questions you are asking would to give be a big chunk of a semester-long QFT course. You might be interested in Tong's lecture notes: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html

Comment: Also quite relevant is this overview by Weinberg: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702027. More details are given in the first few chapters of the first volume of his quantum field theory textbook. However, be aware that these chapters are not easy reading.

Comment: You could equally well ask this in quantum mechanics - there you have some collection of observables (eg position, momentum) - the Hamiltonian is some function of them and the state is given by a state vector. Your point that 'then you only need the Hamiltonian' is also true here.

Comment: @jacob1729  That sounds promising...can you help me with the connection?  In QM, the position and momentum operators have clear physical interpretations.  So e.g. if $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $\hat x$, the eigenvalue $x$ is the definite position of the particle.  But in QFT, if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat\phi (x)$ for some point $x$ in spacetime ... what does the eigenvalue $\phi$ mean?

Comment: Quantum fields are not observable, but momentum and position in quantum mechanics are observables. Also, quantum fields are rather singular objects. $\phi(x)$ is an operator-valued distribution, so a quantum field is not well defined at a point but only after smearing it with some test function $f$, that is, $\int f(x) \phi(x) \mathrm{d} x$ is an operator.